# How does one change the language of an HTML page?

Tags: html, amp-html

Specifically, I am writing in AMP HTML, if there would be any conflictions.

I would like to approach a pretty cool concept of being able to change the language of an HTML page I am working on, just by the click of a button, like so:

```
<button>Parlez-vous Français?</button>
```

I would like the person do be able to click a button that would specifically translate the page into French. But it would be cool to add some animation to it too, like maybe a fade-out/fade-in sort of thing.

How would I be able to approach this?

Comment: Hey there! Welcome to Stackoverflow. I'd like to advice you to have a look at [this page](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to see how you could improve your question.
Quick tips: Show us what you've tried yourself, give us some code examples, ...

Comment: would you like to have separate view for a language or to dynamically change current webpage?

Comment: Just have a link to an identical page with translated content.

Comment: I would like the person do be able to click a button that would specifically translate the page into French. But it would be cool to add some animation to it too, like maybe a fade-out/fade-in sort of thing.

Comment: I suggest using the [Google Translate](https://translate.google.com/manager/website/) widget instead. It has a few different configurations and is very minimal code. Relying upon the browser to pick up the `lang` attribute is iffy at most.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply change it in the HTML tag itself

```
<html lang="fr">
...
</html>
```

considering you know that it's an html attribute. There are many ways you can change it. Storing the change can either be on database or session storage. Hope this helps

Comment: But my main page is in English. Would I need an English version of the page and a French version?

Comment: Yes, there are plenty of ways to handle multi-lingual. This would be a dynamic way and hopes the browser picks it up and does translations accordingly (google translate)

Another solution is to serve a completely different site which is a sub domain... consider 'domain/fr'